# Jucheck.exe java update,use it or remove old version manually ?

Tags: windows, java

just had UAC ask me if i want to use the update jucheck.exe Java (oracle), and i clicked no. If i use this update tool will it automatically remove the old java version or will it remain ? So should i remove and update manually or use Jucheck.exe ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The article [Why should I uninstall older versions of Java from my system?](http://java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml) states:

> In the past, each Java update was installed in a separate directory on your system. However, Java updates are now installed in a single directory.

So ever since they started doing this, newer versions (or minor version updates at least) *should* overwrite older ones. However, it's *highly* recommended that you go to Add/Remove Programs (Programs and Features) and uninstall any older versions of Java (JRE) you spot except the very latest.